# (objective) C side by side translations / comparison to another language

Tags: objective-c, c, language-comparisons

The language comparison / translation on the Dart language website helped me tremendously in learning javascript even though I did not know either Dart or Javascript much! link, http://synonym.dartlang.org/

Is there something similar for objective C or maybe even C ?

Comment: What other language would it be comparing against?

Comment: Dart intentionally has a very close correspondance to JavaScript. Objective-C has similarities to other languages, but direct side-by-side examples can be deceptive — especially since the design patterns that are idiomatic in, say, C++ with Boost and Qt are very different from what you'd use in Objective-C with Cocoa.

Comment: Objective C is a hybrid of two very different languages, and intentionally keeps the syntax of the two halves apart. The non-OO part is nearly identical to C—so close that a side-by-side comparison between them would be pointless. The OO part is based on Smalltalk, and a comparison between the OO parts of ObjC and Smalltalk (or Squeak, F-Script, or even Ruby) might be very useful.